# React Native Failed to build after Installing react-navigation and react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I did the following

```
   react-native init project-name
   yarn add react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler and
   react-native run-android
```

The dependencies installed successfully but the app failed to build with the following errors

```
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugResources FAILED
17 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 9 up-to-date
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-gesture-handler:_
internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aa
pt2:3.4.1-5326820)' to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-android-aapt2-bi
nary, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}.
      > org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not read path 'C:\Users\DevLewa\.g
radle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3d408b3640f7dfba25695085d22596b0\aapt2-3.4.1
-5326820-windows'.
```

I have searched all through github issues but found no helping information, how do I resolve this, I have being on it since morning today.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some of my initialized projects using reac-native cli. it would be solved by running: `react-native link` in your project directory. I hope it would work for you as me.

If it was helpful please vote me up:)

Comment: I have done this just now, It doesn't work. Moreover I am using rn 0.60. and it comes with autolinking

Comment: try this way and I hope it solve your problem. First run react-native run-android and when you get that error run npm start and then reload your app in emulator.